# How to write a shell script to queue and submit a given calculation (in fortran) directing to the nodes?

Tags: bash, shell, slurm, hpc

I have a fortran code (which is working perfectly), I need to submit the queue and direct it to the nodes.

I compiled the fortran code manually. The .bash code gives the following error:

```
Job start at Thu Mar  2 17:58:30 -03 2023
n20
1
Job end at Thu Mar  2 17:58:32 -03 2023
```

This is my .bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=calculos
#SBATCH --partition=cempa
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=20
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --time=10:00:00
#SBATCH --error=error_output_sbatch_%j.txt
#SBATCH --output=error_output_sbatch_%j.txt
#SBATCH --exclusive

echo "Job start at $(date)"

module unload openmpi3
module load gnu8

#Exibe os nós alocados para o Job
echo $SLURM_JOB_NODELIST
echo $SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES

# Operations
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
EXEC=./calculos_jan.x
echo "Job end at $(date)"
exit
```

Comment: It is not really good to completely rewrite your question after you get answers. This is a completely different problem and you should ask it in a new question.

Comment: I rolled back your question. Please ask a new one. Your program was executed with your new script, but crashed. To debug the crash, compile your program for debugging. For example `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all` or `ifort -g -traceback -war -check`. I would recommend to try the program on a normal computer first and run it on a cluster later.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298948/question-answered-but-a-new-issue-appeared https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions and related posts on SO meta.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any command to actually use the executable. Yo are defining a variable `EXEC` with the path to the exacutable, but you do not execute it anywhere.

Either execute it instead of defining the variable or execute `$EXEC` after defining it.

Comment: I put in the next line: mpirun -np 1 $EXEC &> output      / If it fails again, I'll come back here. thanks

Comment: I modified my script and it still keeps giving error.